# Use sqlite CTE to combine update with select to return the matching row regardless of it was updated?

Tags: sqlite

As you probably know, using RETURNING on update doesn't work if the update statement doesn't modify the row. One could make the update unconditional if it's idempotent, but that's going to turn a primarily read operation into an always write operation, which has performance and device wear considerations.

With a CTE you can name the select statement and refer to it more than once, but **how can you update the record selected in the CTE AND return it?**

An example of two queries I want to combine:

```
-- This is the row to update, if needed, and return unconditionally
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?;
-- Update the selected user, but only if isVerified is false
UPDATE users SET isVerified = true WHERE isVerified = false AND id = ?;
```

This question is not a duplicate. I have looked at a dozen similar questions on here and they do not answer the question.

It may be that it's best to use two queries for this. But I'm wondering if it can be done with a single CTE.